# How Jenkins job can return a value

Tags: jenkins

I've one jenkins job that has one java class and it returns a value. How can I make a jenkins build job to store the return value and use in post build step to send out an email based on that return variable value?

Comment: Exec shell: var = $(java - jar mysuperjava)
Exec bash: for /f %i in ("java -jar mysquperjava'') do set VAR=%i

Comment: Sorry Joao I didn't get this. Can you explain this?